# htaccess ReWrite 2 different styles of URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I have two different styles of URLs (below)

```
domain.com/shop/post/post-name
domain.com/shop/?p=123
```

I want to redirect both of these to `domain.com/blog/post/post-name` or `domain.com/blog/post/123`

Currently, I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} post/([^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.itl.uk.net/blog/$1 [R,L]
```

Which redirects the first URL but i'm not sure how to include a rule to redirect both

Comment: Is `/shop/` a real directory?

Comment: yes, it is real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have these rules in `shop/.htaccess`, **just below** `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

# to handle /shop/post/post-name
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^post/.+$ /blog/$0 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

# to handle /shop/?p=123
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /blog/post/%1? [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```